# Pascal Style RailRoad Diagrams

Tags: c++, syntax, pascal

Where can I find pascal-style railroad diagrams to describe C++ syntax?
(As an alternative to EBNF)

Comment: Thanks for useful answers and getting me off the wrong tracl.

Answer (score 1):

There don't exist any, as far as I know. The C++ syntax can't even be expressed in a proper EBNF - it's a context-sensitive grammar, and anything attempting to parse it has to be capable of processing C++ code at least as far as template instantiation and overload resolution (not to mention macros).

Comment: It depends on what the OP wanted. If a full-and-complete syntax description as railroad diagrams, that's one thing. If just a guide to the main parts of the language syntax (which might be the case, given the other questions posted by them) then a partial set might do. A Google search turns up some

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one - the C++ grammar is not only **not** context-free, it's undecidable.  See http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/defective.html#defect-2 and the associated links for a more in-depth discussion.

Comment: undecidable in that context refers to context-sensitivity. The FQA, like all rants, tends to skip the facts slightly (it's still a good source of criticism). The expression AA BB(CC) does depend on the context, but won't give an error for ambiguity. It is very easily decidable based on context.

Comment: Why would being not context-free mean the grammar is undecidable? That's just nonsense, it just means that the grammar is context-dependent. These "ambiguous" constructs like `int a();` are interpreted always and consistently in well-defined ways. That the interpretation, which is dictated by the grammar, might not be what the programmer *wanted* doesn't mean anything is undecidable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there are some railroad diagrams for the C++ diagrams (I don't value these image much) but it is a purely mechanical work to transform EBNF to these diagrams.

About the grammar of C++: If you look at the grammar in the appendix of the C++ standard, that is a **context-free** grammar. The problem with this grammar is that it is an **ambiguous** grammar. Another thing is, the grammar accepts strings that are not valid C++ programs - but this is true about every typed languages with variable declarations. If the gramar was **undecidable**, it would mean that you could not tell for some string if it was generated according to the grammar or not. BTW, it really is undecidable problem whether given C++ file compiles, because templates are Turing-complete.

The reason why this ambiguous grammar is frowned upon is that it makes the parser much more complex, slower and/or needing more memory.